# Xcode application, Splash screen doesnt work on low resolution iPad

Tags: xcode, ipad, react-native, splash-screen

I'm opening a topic here to find some help regarding the Splash screen on iOS. Apparently, all the process seems to be quite simple, but unfortunately, I've encountered a problem just on a specific case : **the default splash screen is showed on the iPads with low resolutions** (iPad , iPad 2, iPad Air , ...), the custom one is not set.

*Specificity :* **The application is developed with React Native (Framework) only for iPad on a Landscape mode.**

Here below you will find the steps that I followed to achieve the Splash screen :

1. *2 pictures prepared for the Splash screen :* Default-Landscape.png (1024*768px) & Default-Landscape@2x.png (2048*1536px).
2. *Project opened on Xcode :* MyProject.xcodeproj
3. *Check out* the folder "**Images.xcassets**" in the project.
4. Left click *(2nd column from the left. In the full display interface)* > App Icon & Launch Image > New iOS Launch Image.
5. *Two new things appeared:* one drop zone and a checklist with the devices that we wanted. Then I've chosen what interested me.
6. *Drag and drop* the images in the specific drop zone related to the good format.
7. After the image uploaded I've click on project "**MyProject**" (1st column) > click on target "**MyProject**" (2nd column) > click on "**Use catalog assets**" (button on the 3rd column) > select "**Migrate**" > then in the drop down menu I've chosen the settings that I've prepared before "**LaunchImage**".
8. Finally I removed the folder "**Base.lproj**" where the default splash screen (LaunchScreen.xid) was.

***Result:*** *After compiling, I've seen that the Splash screen was working for the high resolution devices (iPad Air 2 & iPad Pro), but unfortunatly, on low resolution (iPad 2, iPad Air, iPad Retina), I still have the default screen "NameOfProject" as headline and "Powered by React native" on the bottom of the page.*

I really hope that you can help me on this one because I really don't know what's going wrong there. I've tried different import methods, differents sizes and names for the images. But still nothing work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to delete the app from the Home screen, and then reinstall it. iOS seems to cache the previous launch image for some reason.

Also make sure that your image sizes are correct if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot rclai89!!

Just to add some details to complete this topic. This video explains what you've advised me and solved my problem : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiSehGHZZ18.

- *App removed from the Home screen :* Once the emulator is running, on the top navigation choose **Simulator** > then **Reset Content and settings**.
- *Cache cleared :* CMD + SHIFT + K
- *Derived Data cleared :* On Xcode go to the **Window** item (top navigation) > select **Projects** > next to the *"Derived Data"* you have the path where the file is contained, just need to click on **Delete** button and everything is done.

**Close & Re-Open Xcode.** The next compilation for all the different devices (in my case iPad) show up the splash screen that I wanted. Awesome!